# Apply IQueryable reference on another object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have the next code:

```
var list1 = server1Products; // server1Products is List<Product> type
var list2 = server2Products; // server2Products is List<Product> type
//
// get a queryable reference from first variable (list1)
var query = list1.AsQueryable();
//
// apply any filter
query = query.Where(p => p.Active == true);
//
// get result from first list server1Products
var result1 = query.ToList();
```

I need to apply the **SAME "query" reference** on the variable "list2".

```
var result2 = ??????????????; // result from server2Products list
```

It is possible?

Comment: You mean `result2 = query.Where(somethingelse)`?

Comment: Let's get things straight first. Why do you use `.AsQueryable()`?

Comment: Hi @GertArnold... I simplified the matter, this is a bit more complex. I need to build a complex LINQ expression and apply it on many lists

Comment: Hi @DavidG.... Yes! where "somethingelse" is the same LINQ expression that I applied on the first list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to apply the same filter to another list so you will get only active products from the list2. You can make it this way:

```
Expression<Func<Product, bool>> expr = p => p.Active;
var result1 = list1.AsQueryable().Where(expr);
var result2 = list2.AsQueryable().Where(expr);
```

Calling the `AsQueryable()` method is correct here as other way C# won’t resolve the right method properly.

Comment: You may as well use a `Func<Product, bool>` without `AsQueryable()`. I suspect that the OP expects some magic to happen by using `AsQueryable()`, but they don't respond.

Comment: Yes, you’re right. The usage of such approach that I’ve found is to make unit tests for filters. When you have a set of filters which return Expressions for further usage with ORM and you have to test them - you wouldn’t be able to do that without calling the AsQueryable method to your test lists. I don’t know any other places where this method would be appropriate.